# How can I disable autogrowth in SQL Server wide and preserve the data in case of revert

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a way to disable autogrowth of all files of all dbs in SQL Server wide using SQL commands.

I found that I can use `ALTER DATABASE ... FILEGROWTH = 0` from [MSFT doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options?view=sql-server-ver16), but this means I would lose the autogrowth value for these files and not able to revert it to original value when re-enabling it (i need to specify a value when re-enable it)

If doing it from UI, there is a disable button that can preserve the data. Is there any way that I can do the same using SQL commands, ie., simply disable the autoGrowth without losing the data ?

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the growth setting from [sys.master_files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (growth and is_percent_growth columns) and store it in a table somewhere.  This would allow you to construct a rollback script.

This is an unusual request though.  Typically you would disable auto growth to expand your DB to a new volume - creating a new file and disabling the auto-growth on the old file.  I can't think of a good reason to disable auto growth server-wide.  If the files need to grow and auto-growth isn't enabled, your queries will fail.  It can be a good practice to grow your files manually - but it's still worth leaving auto-grow enabled.